# How can I "poke" an android application that adheres to the Observer pattern?

Tags: android, observer-pattern

I've got a small android application that implements the [Observer pattern.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern)

I want my "subject" (or the thing being observed) to change its state, such as changing its String from `hello` to `hello world`.

How can I do this via the emulator?

I need my (observing) android application to still run in the foreground so it can display whatever is being observed, but I need to find some way to alter the state of the observed object, is it possible to do this via the command line? How else can I "poke" the observed object to change its state.

One dirty-hack method I can think of is to set the observed object up in a loop, so every 10 seconds it changes its state, but that is not good as then I won't have control over it.

Comment: You can't alter a Java object from the command line.  Perhaps if you explained what you are trying to accomplish with the observer pattern, we could direct you to a good solution.

Comment: My app will eventually communicate with a 3rd party library (most like I will have a JAR included in my project that it will use). I want to mock the 3rd party library for the moment, hence wanting to push data to my observer in my android app

Comment: Is there anything specific to Android development about this question?  Or is it a general how-to for Observer/Observable in Java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct answer: write a test case, and have the test case "poke" the observed object.

Not-quite-as-correct answer: add stuff to your activity to "poke" the observed object.

Comment: Cheers Mark, that'll do. (Good talks at DroidCon UK by the way;) )